# How to go back from a PageStack's Page to the parent tab in the UI Toolkit

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, pagestack

So [in a previous question](https://askubuntu.com/q/463869/9781) I tried to use the Ubuntu UI Toolkit to nest a PageStack within the Tabs component. It seemed to work, but it had its quirks, so I'm now trying another option, which in theory should have the same effect [according to the documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.Tabs/).

However, with the code below, I've noticed the following: upon opening page3, if I then pull the toolbar and tap on the Back button, it always returns me to to the initial Tab in Tabs, instead of the actual tab that the page was loaded from.

That is, `page3` is loaded from `tab2`, but if I open the page, pull the toolbar from the bottom and hit Back, I'm returned to `tab1` instead.

How can I make it so that tapping Back returns me to `tab2`?

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

MainView {
    id: mainView
    width: units.gu(38)
    height: units.gu(50)

    PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        Component.onCompleted: push(tabs)

        Tabs {
            id: tabs
            Tab {
                id: tab1
                title: "Tab 1"
                page: Page {
                    Label {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Use header to navigate between tabs"
                    }
                }
            }
            Tab {
                id: tab2
                title: "Tab 2"
                page: Page {
                    Button {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        onClicked: pageStack.push(page3)
                        text: "Press"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Page {
            id: page3
            visible: false
            title: "Page on stack"
            Label {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Press back to return to the tabs"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write a tag wiki/excerpt for pagestack, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug recently introduced into the UI Toolkit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1316736

Once that is fixed, it will once again return you to the previously selected tab when going back to the Tabs page of a PageStack.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to define a custom back button in a toolbar assigned to `page3`'s `tools` property. With that, I can replicate what the standard Back button does in terms of going back to the root of the PageStack and then choose which tab to go back to.

```js
ToolbarItems {

    back: ToolbarButton {
        action: Action {
            text: i18n.tr("Back")
            iconName: "back"
            onTriggered: {
                pageStack.pop();
                // It'd be neater to use `selectedTab`, but it's read-only
                tabs.selectedTabIndex = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```